# How to implement recursive search filter in agngulrjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

There is a multi level java script object.Then I print these object using ng-repeat recursively.Now I filter the nodes.When I give the search string it only shows the matching string.But what I am looking for is it should filter along with its parent tree.Example if I search for keyword "self" then there are two nodes having "Self" keyword.They are

- Pateint: Self
- D or DA: Self / Care team

And their parent is

- Step 1: User types allowed to access

and it's parent is

- Access details

and it's parent is

- Master

.Like this hierarchy it should filter. But it filter only

- Pateint: Self
- D or DA: Self / Care team

Suppose in search box I give keyword "Self". It should return

- Master

  - Access details

    - Step 1: User types allowed to access

      - Pateint: Self
      - D or DA: Self / Care team

But it return

- Pateint: Self
- D or DA: Self / Care team

What I am looking for is if a string is searched it should show along with its parent node.
How to solve?Please help.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

console.log(22);

$scope.categories = [
    {"id":"1","linkStatus":"no","title":"Master","tag":["head"],"categories":[{"id":"1.1","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'userRole'})","title":"User roles","tag":["ur","ru"]},{"id":"1.2","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'assets'})","title":"Assets","tag":["as","st"]},{"id":"1.3","linkStatus":"no","title":"Access details","tag":["ad","da"],
        "categories":[{"id":"1.3.1","linkStatus":"no","title":"Step 1: User types allowed to access","tag":["tf","ft"],"categories":[{"id":"1.3.1.1","linkStatus":"no","title":"Pateint: Self","tag":["ps","sp"]},{"id":"1.3.1.2","linkStatus":"no","title":"D or DA: Self / Care team","tag":["ct","tc"]},{"id":"1.3.1.3","linkStatus":"no","title":"Admin: Everyone","tag":["av","va"]}]},{"id":"1.3.2","linkStatus":"no","title":"Step 2: Plugin relevance for different roles or types","tag":["po","op"],"categories":[{"id":"1.3.2.1","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'plugins'})","title":"Step 2a: User plugins","tag":["sd","ds"]},{"id":"1.3.2.2","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'eventPlugins'})","title":"Step 2b: Event plugins","tag":["aw","wa"]}]}]

    },{"id":"1.4","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'appPermission'})","title":"App access details","tag":["wa","aw"]},{"id":"1.5","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'careTeam'})","title":"Care Team","tag":["df","fd"]},{"id":"1.6","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'apptNoteConfig'})","title":"Appointment Note Configuration","tag":["dj","jd"]},{"id":"1.7","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'noteLockPermission'})","title":"Note lock permission settings","tag":["rr","yy"]},{"id":"1.8","linkStatus":"yes","link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'locations'})","title":"Savant Care office locations","tag":["rr","yy"]}]


    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "linkStatus":"no",
        "title":"Billing",
        "tag":["t","jt"],
        "categories":[
            {
                "id":"2.1",
                "linkStatus":"yes",
                "link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'eligibleDetail'})",
                "title":"Eligible Details",
                "tag":["we","ew"]
            },{
                "id":"2.2",
                "linkStatus":"yes",
                "link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'cptCodes'})",
                "title":"CPT",
                "tag":["dd","ss"],
                "categories":[
                    {
                        "id":"2.2.1",
                        "linkStatus":"yes",
                        "link":"masterDb.sectionPage({sectionName: 'cptCodesRates'})",
                        "title":"CPT code ratesz",
                        "tag":["ss","ww"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },


];

});

app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function(items, searchString) {

        var arr=[];
        if (!searchString) {
            return items;
        }
        else
        {
            var countdown = function(items)
            {

                angular.forEach(items, function (value, key) {
                    var title=value.title.toLowerCase();

                    if(title.indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
                    {
                        arr.push(value);
                    }
      if('categories' in value)
                     {
                            return countdown(value.categories);
                     }

                })


            }
            countdown(items);
            return arr;



        }

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">

    <span ng-if="category.linkStatus=='yes'">
        <a ui-sref="{{category.link}}" ui-sref-active="activeState"> {{ category.title }}</a>
    </span>
    <span ng-if="category.linkStatus=='no'">
         {{ category.title }}
    </span>
    <ul ng-if="category.categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories | myFilter:test" ng-include="'categoryTree'">
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories | myFilter:test " ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I want to search a child node.If it have a parent node then it should also display.But in my code it only show the search node.I tried in jsfiddle and gave the link

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? And more specifically, did you follow the link to [mcve] and read that too?

Comment: I am new in stack overflow. That's why I don't know all the ruls and regulations. I write the code in jsfiddle link is: 
jsfiddle.net/subhajitmaity/d8371L1x/1/
The search filter should give the expected node describe in above.But in my example it don't show the expected node.Actually what I actually looking for is that if I search a string it shows along with its parent tree.If you visit the link you will understand

Comment: We've all been new, which is why I'm pointing you to the rules and guidelines. But you don't seem to be reading them. Your question should stand on it's own, without needing to visit external links since they're out of the control of this site and might change, thereby making the questions and answers here meaningless. Furthermore, you should strive to reproduce your problem with as little code as possible if you want anyone to bother looking at it. The more effort you put into explaining your problem, the more likely it is that you'll get help. And right now it isn't looking very likely.

Comment: Now please look. I am giving the code.And describe what I am looking for

Comment: Much better! But I still think a smaller example focusing on the actual problem, a description of what your thoughts were when you wrote this and what specifically you're stuck on would be even better. However, if you think this is good enough, we'll just have to see how many people come here to help. I'm not trying to be mean, I'm actually trying to help you. People here are already volunteering their free time, they're not going to jump through hoops to do it too.

Comment: I already change the description>Please look into that